# Understanding tty + bash

Tags: bash, tty

I see that I can use one bash session to print text in another as follows

```
echo './myscript' > /dev/pts/0 # assuming session 2 is using this tty
# or
echo './myscript' > /proc/1500/fd/0 # assuming session 2's pid is 1500
```

But why does the text `./myscript` only print and not execute? Is there anything that I can do to execute my script this way?

(I know that this will attract a lot of criticism which will perhaps fill any answers that follow with "DON'T DO THAT!" but the real reason I wish to do this is to automatically supply a password to `sshfs`. I'm working with a local WDMyCloud system, and it deletes my `.authorized_keys` file every night when I turn off the power.)

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use a FIFO and read the password from it?

Comment: @Cez : Do you mean after making the FIFO redirecting ssh to read from it? Like `ssh myserver < myfifo`? In my recent experience, it appears that ssh commands refuse to read passwords from redirects. I'm not sure what the mechanics are, but I suppose it's a security measure. do you know otherwise?

Comment: @Cez : I have just repeated the experiment that I think you proposed, using the command given in my comment above. It's not effective.

Comment: I don't think that any ssh related app will accept a password from stdin. You would be better automating the keys copy.

Comment: @JellicleCat I've added an answer that shows you what I was meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does the text ./myscript only print and not execute?

Input and output are two different things.

Writing to a terminal puts data on the screen. Reading from a terminal reads input from the keyboard. In no way does writing to the terminal simulate keyboard input.

There's no inherent coupling between input and output, and the fact that keys you press show up on screen at all is a conscious design decision: the shell simply reads a key, and then both appends it to its internal command buffer, and writes a copy to the screen.

This is purely for your benefit so you can see what you're typing, and not because the shell in any way cares what's on the screen. Since it doesn't, writing more stuff to screen has no effect on what the shell executes.

> Is there anything that I can do to execute my script this way?

Not by writing to a terminal, no.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a FIFO:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FIFO="$(mktemp)"
rm -fv "$FIFO"

mkfifo "$FIFO"

( echo testing123 > "$FIFO" ) &

cat "$FIFO" | sshfs -o password_stdin testing@localhost:/tmp $HOME/tmp
```

How you store the password and send it to the FIFO is up to you

Comment: +1 Thanks. I was not aware of the `password_stdin` option for `sshfs` because it doesn't exist for `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by using an ioctl system call:

> The  ioctl()  system  call  manipulates the underlying device parameters of special files.  In particular, many operating characteristics of character special files (e.g., terminals) may be controlled with ioctl() requests.

For the 'request' argument of this system call, you'll want `TIOCSTI`, which is defined as `0x5412` in my header files. (`grep -r TIOCSTI /usr/include` to verify for your environment.)

I accomplish this as follows in ruby:

```rb
fd = IO.sysopen("/proc/#{$$}/fd/0", 'wb')
io = IO.new(fd, 'wb')
"puts 9 * 16\n".chars.each { |c| io.ioctl 0x5412, c };
```